# Load comments dynamically in django using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I want to load all the comments of a particular article when a user clicks on the corresponding comments link. I want to do this with Jquery Ajax without refreshing the page but not able to achieve my motive. I have shared my idea over here. If this is not the relevant method than please suggest me another approach.

```html
                       
                       
//articles/all_articles.html

<div class="infinite-container">
  <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button> 
    {% for article in all_articles %}
     <div class="infinite-item">
       <ul id="posts_ul">
  {% include 'articles/indivisual_article.html' with article=article %} 
       </ul>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
</div>

//articles/indivisual_articles.html

<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" class="comment" id="allcomments" value="{{article.id}}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> 
{% trans 'Comment' %}
(<span class="comment-count">{{article.comments }}</span>)
</a><br>
<ol class="clearfix">
{% comment %} 
Place holder to load feed comments {% endcomment %}
</ol>
```

```js
<scripts type='text/javascript'> $('#allcomments').on("click",function(){
    var myvar= $(this).attr("value");
    var $el1= $(this);
    var $p1= $el1.parent();
    var $list= $p1.find(".clearfix");
      $.ajax(
       url: '/articles/comment/',
       type: 'POST',
       data:{post_id: myvar},
       dataType:'json',
       success: function(response) {
        queryset= .parseJSON(response);
          for(i=0; i<(queryset.count); i++){
                       value=response[i].comment
                       $list.html(<li>"{{value}}"= + value</li>).load()           
                     });
                     
                      
    }); 
    
</scripts>
```

```html
//views.py

@login_required    
def comment(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        article_id= request.POST.get('post_id')
        article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        comment=ArticleComment.objects.filter(post=article)
        response=serializers.serialize('json', list(comment), fields=('comment'))
        
        return HttpResponse(response, mimetype='application/json') 
        
//models.py

class Article(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    post=models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    create_user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    

class ArticleComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)    
    
//urls.py

urlpatterns= [url(r'^articles/comment/$', views.comment, name='art_comment'),]
```

Comment: whats the expected outcome? and what are you getting?

Comment: I am not receiving any output. The page just refreshes adding /#/ to the original url and not doing anything.

Comment: I expect that on clicking the comments link I get a dropdown list displaying all the comments of that particular article(like quora).

Comment: @pancho018 I expect that on clicking the comments link I get all the comments displayed under the article. I changed my code from .parseJSON(response) to JSON.parse(response) and the console isnt throwing any error. However just to check whether my server is returning any response or not I wrote the code console.log(response) in the success function. But the console isn't showing any result. Please if you can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code that print the comment is ok:

```
$list.html(<li>"{{value}}"= + value</li>).load()
```

I think html() expect htmlString as a param, can you try this?:

```
$list.html("<li>" + value + "</li>")
```

Can you check if there're any error in your browser's console?

**UPDATE:**

This's working for me:

**indivisual_article.html**

Note {{article.articlecomment_set.count }} to get the comments number

```
{{ article.title }}
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" class="comment" id="allcomments" value="{{article.id}}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
    (<span class="comment-count">{{article.articlecomment_set.count }}</span>)
</a>
<br>

<ol class="clearfix">
    {% comment %}
        Place holder to load feed comments
    {% endcomment %}
</ol>
```

**view.py**

I've used JsonResponse and GET method.

```
def comment(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        article_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
        article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        comments = ArticleComment.objects.filter(post=article)
        response = serializers.serialize('json', comments),
        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

**Javascript**

- Change Scripts for Script
- Missing "{" in $.ajax(**{**
- Use GET
- Change queryset.count to queryset.length, it's a js array
- Then, you must get the comment name from queryset: queryset[i].fields.comment

You can try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#allcomments').on("click",function(){
        var myvar= $(this).attr("value");
        var $el1= $(this);
        var $p1= $el1.parent();
        var $list= $p1.find(".clearfix");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/articles/comment/',
            type: 'GET',
            data:{post_id: myvar},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(response) {
                queryset= JSON.parse(response);
                var comment_list = '';
                for(i=0; i<queryset.length; i++){
                    comment_list = comment_list + "<li>"+queryset[i].fields.comment+"</li>";
                }
                $list.html(comment_list)
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I changed my code from .parseJSON(response) to JSON.parse(response) and the console isnt throwing any error. However just to check whether my server is returning any response or not I wrote the code console.log(response) in the success function. But the console isn't showing any result. Please if you can solve this problem.

Comment: Probably you're getting an error in the response and the success method is not executed? First, can you try to change from POST to GET (It's more appropiate if you don't make changes in the server data) and then, write the url (articles/comment/?post_id=xx) in the browser and check if the server response is ok.

Comment: I tried the above changes but to no effect. The console isn't responding any thing neither any response nor any error.